# How To Format a JSON Text In Python?

Tags: python, json, api, python-3.x

When I call the JSON file for Vincent van Gogh's List of Works wikipedia page, using [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=json&action=query&titles=list%20of%20works%20by%20Vincent%20van%20Gogh&Page&prop=revisions&rvprop=content) url,
it obviously returns a huge blob of text which I believe is some sort of dictionary of lists.

Now, someone has already shown me Python's import wikipedia feature, so skip that. How can I decode this JSON? I feel like I have tried everything in Python 3's library, and always get an error, like I get if I try this code for example:

```
data = urllib.request.urlopen(long_json_url)
stuff = json.load(data)   #or json.loads(data)
print(stuff)
```

it returns

```
TypeError: the JSON object must be str, not 'bytes'
```

Or if I try this code:

```
data = urllib.request.urlopen(longurl)
json_string = data.read().decode('utf-8')
json_data = json.loads(json_string)
print(json_data)
```

It doesn't return an error, but just what looks like nothing

```
>>>

>>>
```

But if I highlight that empty space and paste it, it pastes the same blob of text.

`{'warnings': {'main': {'*': "Unrecognized parameter: 'Page'"}}, 'query': {'normalized': [{'from': 'list of works by Vincent van Gogh',`... etc

If I try a for loop:

```
for entry in json_data:
    print(entry)
```

It returns

```
>>> 
query
warnings
>>>
```

And that's it. So it's not returning an error there, but not really much else, just two values? How would you make the JSON data into a workable Python dict or list? Or at the very least, into a more vertical format that I could actually read?

Comment: *it always returns an error* - to save people running and trying your code - please [edit] what that error is into your post, as well as examples of *I have tried several things* - what are they - what errors/nothing do they give etc... ?

Comment: +1 from me for taking the time to improve your question - very good job :)

Answer (score 2):

> How would you make the JSON data into a workable Python dict or list?

You're already doing that with

```
json_data = json.loads(json_string)
```

This however:

```
for entry in json_data:
    print(entry)
```

will only print the `keys` of your dictionaries. If you want to print the values, you need to use:

```
for entry in json_data:
    print(json_data[entry])
```

if you inspect the data, you'll see that there are two `keys` for the main dictionary. The ones you already got by iterating over the dict:

```
{u'query': {...}, u'warnings': {...}}
```

Comment: Thank you, I suspected as much, and that is what I was afraid of. The entire blob of data in this JSON file is one single value that is mapped to one key, a key which is inside a dictionary nested in another dictionary in a dictionary in a dictionary. What on Earth is the use of this wikipedia API? Disappointing. Thank you so much for helping me realize this.

Comment: I have begun to sort through the values in this dictionary. I am making progress. Thank you again.

Comment: @rami7 You're welcome! Yeah, unfortunately the entire actual content seems to be in some other format. Let me know, if you have any other questions.